# Invalid HTML - Quoting Attributes

Tags: php, html, quotes

I have following HTML:

```
<td width=140 style='width:105.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
       mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:#666666'>OCCUPANCY
       TAX:</span></p>
</td>
```

Some of the HTML attributes are not quoted, like for example: width=140 and class=MsoNormal

Are there any PHP function for that sort of thing, if not what would be the clever way of sanitizing this in HTML?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no native php function, and it's already sanitized. The **only** time that `""` are *really* required are when there are special characters or spaces present in the value. Given that, I think it'd be best to just clean the files up yourself, using a text editor such as sublime.

Comment: I have to solve this programmatically. width=140 without quotes gives me trouble because I'm using quoted_printable_decode() function and when it finds =140 converts it to some unvanted character. However with='140' (with quotes) is fine. But I would like some clever way of quoting all of the attributtes in entire file.

Comment: Maybe [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I advise you to not use inline styling. Separate your style from your markup, it will save you a lot of headaches. Believe me.

Comment: @Nuno Aruda this is HTML I get, I didn't wrote it. I have to work with it.

Comment: The HTML is not invalid. Attribute values only require quotes if the value includes particular characters (and [0-9][a-z][A-Z] are not among them). It sounds like your problem is that you are trying to decode data using quoted_printable_decode when it isn't encoded that way in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could use regexp for this:

```
/\s([\w]{1,}=)((?!")[\w]{1,}(?!"))/g


\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
1st Capturing group ([\w]{1,}=)
    [\w]{1,} match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: {1,} Between 1 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    = matches the character = literally
2nd Capturing group ((?!")[\w]{1,}(?!"))
    (?!") Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
    " matches the characters " literally
    [\w]{1,} match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: {1,} Between 1 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    (?!") Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
    " matches the characters " literally
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Which would be implemented something like this:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\s([\w]{1,}=)((?!")[\w]{1,}(?!"))/', function($matches){
    return ' '.$matches[1].'"'.$matches[2].'"';
}, $str);
```

And would result in:

```
 <td width="140" style='width:105.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>
   <p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:#666666'>OCCUPANCY
      TAX:</span></p>
 </td>
```

[Eval.in live example](https://eval.in/218788)

Note, this is a down and dirty example, and can surely be cleaned up.

Comment: Obligatory "you can't parse HTML with regex": http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1902010